# Making SQL code into an interface

Tags: sql, visual-studio

noob SQL coder here.. At my company, we're just using simple SQL to unlock a file that someone is in, then left for the day..

Running this script basically unlocks the file so other users can access that file.

I want to turn this into some other application so managers can just type in the file number into a field, and hit a button to execute, so they don't go have to run this script using SQL Server studio.

I'm unsure where to start?

Any help would be greatly appreciate it!

```
--Script to unlock an order
begin try
    begin tran

 declare @orderName as nvarchar(max) 

 --Please enter an order number to unlock
set @orderName = 'ORDER NUMBER'

delete 
   from 
    core.Lock 
 where ObjectIdentifier in (select guid from pf.[order] where Number = @orderName)

 commit      
end try
begin catch
      rollback
      print error_message()   
end catch
```

Comment: Where will the application run? What language do you want to use?

Comment: We have SSRS reporting site up internally that managers access for reporting purposes. Anyway this can be put into SSRS?

Comment: You want SSRS to be deleting records?

Answer (score 1):

I could post you the entire code you need but you will learn nothing. So ill offer some hints. Make this query/script into a Stored Procedure, youll need to define some parameters for the file number. Id also get it to return something on success.

Then, create a new C# application and take a look here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37hwc7kt(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I can give you the code but im sure others will agree that you will learn more if you code it youself instead of just copying and pasting. Hope it works out well for you.